# Facing an error with IndexError: list assignment out of range

Tags: python, excel, list, tokenize

I don't know how to use Python as I've never learned it before. Hence, I require some help from the community if that is possible.

I've been trying to code out a program that loops through every single cell in the stated column and tokenize it for it to be stored in an array.

So far, the array hasn't been working, when I used the for-loop to check that if the word registered is in the stop-words, it only appends the last sentence with the code `first_list.append(i)`

With the following code

```
import xlrd
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/L31101/Documents/Data/Copy_1.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(8)
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

randomnumber = 0
k = 0
first_list = []

num_cols = sheet.ncols # Number of columns
for row_idx in range(0, sheet.nrows): # Iterate through rows
    print('-'*200)
    print('Row: %s' % row_idx) # Print row number
    for col_idx in range(6, 7): # Iterate through columns
        cell_obj = sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx) # Get cell object by row, col
        first_tokenization = sent_tokenize(cell_obj.value)
        second_tokenization = word_tokenize(cell_obj.value)

    for i in second_tokenization:
        if i is not stop_words:
            first_list[k] = i
            k += 1


print(first_list)
```

it gives the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/L31101/PycharmProjects/FYP/Trial&Error.py", line 24, in <module> first_list[k] = i 
IndexError: list assignment index out of range 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Not to mention, checking the stop_words for-loop doesn't work.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Andric

Comment: Please post the full traceback of your error message. Also: `for col_idx in range(6, 7):` - is this right? This is just 6. Why would you use a loop for this?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/L31101/PycharmProjects/FYP/Trial&Error.py", line 24, in <module>
    first_list[k] = i
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Sorry, like I said, I'm fairly new to Python. Never learned it before, just searched it up on how to do sentiment analysis and this is the code given to me.

Comment: Please always add additional information by editing the question. Many people don't read comments and you can't properly format your code in comments. As for the error message - `first_list` is an empty list, so `first_list[0]` is out of range. `first_list.append(i)` adds a new element to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Doesn't first_list[k] = i also works as append and then k+=1 would increase the position of the k and then add in more things in the loop.

Comment: You might want to read some tutorials about Python lists: http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#lists